# Card Printing Systems compatible with CiviCRM

Tags: civimember, printing

Can anybody recommend a membership card printing system which will enable printing of standard credit card sized plastic membership cards which will draw data from CiviCRM and add a photo to the card using a camera, in real time. The photo may optionally be then stored in CiviCRM if we so choose.

Answer (score 4):

The other option to print Membercard is using  an extension developed by Webaccess Global which generates card in pdf format.

https://github.com/kurund/com.webaccessglobal.membershipcard

Answer (score 3):

I have a client that uses CardExchange Producer to print their membership cards using real-time CiviCRM data.

Note that compatible systems will most likely want to connect to your database via a MySQL connection - and since CiviCRM is most often hosted on a web server outside the office, that presents a technical challenge.  You should be prepared to do some sort of VPN or tunneling between your web server and CiviCRM for real-time connections.  My client uses Windows, so I configured [Plink](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) to connect to the server with an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'll let our DBA figure out the connection issues :)